# Texture paint blend mode issue

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, blend-modes

I seem to be getting this very annoying black line around my brush strokes when I use a lot of the different blend modes (Linear light in my image, on the beard), whilst texture painting. It make the blend modes virtually useless. Anyone have any idea why it's doing this? (2.79)

Much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: There are some limitations with the blend modes when painting in texture paint - and I am not sure what causes it. I am trying to reproduce the effect in 2.8, but when I paint with a color sampled from the target area and then switch blend modes, I don't see much of this - though I do see it in 2.79. Could you test 2.8 on a single image texture and see if it does the same?